# Is there a fast way to copy and paste function arguments to R console

Tags: r, function, debugging

using R and debugging, I often might have a function with several arguments set by default.

e.g.

```
foo <- function(x=c(3,4,5), y= 'house', dateidx = '1990-01-01'){}
```

Often I just want to manually run through some lines in the function, while using the pre-set parameters. If the parameter list is long, I have to type or paste each argument to the console manually before stepping through the function.

```
x=c(3,4,5)
y= 'house'
dateidx = '1990-01-01'
```

It's ok if the list of arguments is small but if there is a long list of arguments, it gets tedious.  Is there some way to just copy the whole set of arguments, paste to console, and do something like unlist, so that all the arguments are passed to the console as if I manually passed each one?

p.s. I'm weakly familiar with the debug tool, but sometimes I find it easier and faster to just troubleshoot lines quickly and manually as above.

Comment: I'm not that adept at using the debug tool, but in my limited experience, it takes time to enter, step, exit etc.. Maybe I need to work more at it. But sometimes I run into this situation and wish to just quickly manually debug a line or two.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the line you want to debug and just running rather than stepping through your code?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't used it all that much and spend so much time trying to use it properly, I end up doing the above. I suppose the answer is that if I become more proficient at the tool, it would be just as fast or easier to approach it that way then? Also, I'm not certain if the debug tool allows for changing/adjusting specific parameters on the fly, as I"m stepping through... above I can just manually enter one parameter and rerun, say one line.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy pre-existing way to do this--mainly because this a problem solved by the debugger.

One could imagine hacking something together that might parse these parameters with a regex and set them automatically--or something like that.  However, the effort would be much better spent learning how to use the debugger.

It should be quite quick to test the part of the code you are interested in with the debugger if you learn how to use it.  [RStudio has a visual debugger](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200713843-Debugging-with-RStudio).  Using this, you can simply mark the command you are interested in testing with a breakpoint and run the script.  The script will run until it reaches the breakpoint, then stop there so you can inspect what is happening.

Comment: seems reasonable. Thanks. Is there a good reference on getting more proficient at it (besides just the help file). texts, etc?